# Run VBA code from external trigger?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to create a macro to run on one workbook, triggered from an other workbook, when the first document is saving?

Some background: I convert a PDF document -- that holds the data I need -- to an Excel document. The conversion can only be done to an .xlxs document. I could just "save as" this document to a macro-enabled document after that, but the whole process would take longer and the entire objective is to drastically cut down time.

I have a macro that can pull data from the .xlsx file to a .xlsm file, so I can manipulate the data as I need from there. Getting it there automatically when I update the .xlxs file is the issue.

Below is the code I currently have made up to import the data from the .xlsx file into the macro-enabled Excel document. Is it possible to have this automatically pull data whenever I make changes and save the .xlsx file without ever having to open either?

```
Sub Import_Test()     
    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_Path As String

    Target_Path = "H:\Test.xlsx"
    Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open("H:\Test.xlsx")
    Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(35, 1)
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = Target_Data
    Source_data = Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
    Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(35, 1) = Source_data
    Source_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: You could create an event sub that fires when you save one workbook, but I don't know of a way to push data to a closed workbook. Regardless, this would necessitate a macro in your ".xlsx" workbook, which would necessitate that becoming a ".xlsm" workbook. This could probably be done with python, or some other high level prgramming language. General approach would be to create a file watcher than triggered a script every time your ".xlsx" file changed. You may hit a snag with the workbook being open though.

Comment: How do you launch the PDF-to-Excel conversion? From a batch script? You could then create a VBS script (a `.vbs` file) which you would launch in the same batch script, and which could create an Excel object, and run on the Excel file contents, potentially saving it under another name, ...etc.

Comment: I am using Adobe ExportPDF to convert. I have limited options due to being at the mercy of my companies Inventory program.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it- you have 2 options:
1) Create a workbook that constantly checks the lastmodified date of your '.xlsx' workbook and as soon as it changes, trigger a macro... downside to this is you have to have it open to be working.
2) Which I believe is the preferred method, is switching the .xlsx file to a .xlsm or .xlsb file, which as others have pointed out is really the only way to get the functionality you're looking for and switch the PDF creation method to the built-in PDF creating functions from the Adobe you're currently using...

In either scenario you have to compromise one of your requirements, option 1 requires a workbook to be open, and option 2 requires you switch PDF method. I think option 2 would be by far the preferred route as long as there wasn't some reason the PDF absolutely had to be created with Adobe PDF maker...

Here's the code to the built in PDF creator if you can use it:
"Thisworkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="filename", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True"

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode